# Не назначается стиль создаваемым элементам в цикле

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1

У меня есть цикл(около 30 итераций) в котором я вызываю функцию, создающую новый объект `Polyline`:

```
    private Polyline MakeArrow()
    {
        Polyline pl = new Polyline();
        pl.Style = Resources["ClosedTheme_Arrow"] as Style;

        return pl;
    }
```

Проблема в том, что стиль назначается только первому элементу.
Если перенести стиль из `XAML` непосредственно в `behind-code`, то все работает как надо:

```
    private Polyline MakeArrow()
    {
        Polyline pl = new Polyline();
        //pl.Style = Resources["ClosedTheme_Arrow"] as Style;

        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.PointCollection pc = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.PointCollection();
        pc.Add(new Windows.Foundation.Point(0, 0));
        pc.Add(new Windows.Foundation.Point(4, 5));
        pc.Add(new Windows.Foundation.Point(0, 10));
        pl.Points = pc;
        pl.Stroke = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);

        return pl;
    }
```

Можно конечно оставить и второй вариант, просто хочется понять, почему в первом случае программа так неявно(с моей точки зрения) себя ведет.

---

Код стиля в **XAML**:

```
<Style x:Key="ClosedTheme_Arrow" TargetType="Polyline">
    <Setter Property="Points" Value="0,0 4,5 0,10"/>
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#fff"/>
</Style>
```

---

Методом "научного тыка" выяснилось, что проблема именно в этой строке стиля:

```
<Setter Property="Points" Value="0,0 5,4 10,0"/>
```

Именно она назначается только первому элементу. Либо сваливает все элементы в одно место и кажется что видно только один элемент.

Comment: А как выглядит `Resources["ClosedTheme_Arrow"]`?

Comment: @NewDevelop Там обычный объект стиля, ничего подозрительного там не нашел

Comment: у меня немного безумная мысль - может, надо `pl.Style = new Resources["ClosedTheme_Arrow"]`?

Comment: @NewDevelop Не компилится так